# how to display openCV Mat image at UWP C++ App Window

Tags: c++, opencv, uwp

how to display openCV Mat type image in UWP APP with C++?

i want to make image processing app by UWP C++ with openCV
for example, read 2 images and overlay them and display the result image at UWP APP window

i am dealing with the image using cv::Mat structure and i assume that in xaml using  tag to display the result image

i try searching using some keywords(ex, uwp, c++, openCV, MAT, Bitmapimage, .etc) but i could not find appropriate solution

is there any solution? or other proper approach?

Comment: look for how to show a bitmap in UWP. then construct that bitmap from the contents of your cv::Mat using its `data` field and other attributes

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you for the comment. i found useful youtube contents (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZT5Dc6PPp0) which do just like you said.